# Rails, how add to method html/js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For example, I have a lot of similar pages. With only one difference: on each of this page (they have different controller) they have different variable, what apply to this html.erb file.

For example, video post html.erb

```
<% for post in @posts_for_video>
  here some html
  and javascript
  and also ruby code injection
<% end %>
```

Video controller:

```
@posts_for_video = Post.where(photo: true)
```

And my photos page:

```
<% for post in @post_for_photos >
  same html as video
  same js as video
  and same ruby code as video
<% end %>
```

Photo controller:

```
@posts_for_photo = Post.where(video: photo)
```

*So my question: Is there any possibility to put html+js+ruby_code to, for example `application_controller.rb`?*

*Or is there any possibility to pass variable to _some.html.erb as a parameter?*

I think, what I'm looking for is (in application_controller.rb):

```
def posts_for_all(post_variable)
  for post in post_variable
    html: post.theme
    js: post.animation
    ruby: some methods
  end
end
```

Comment: Why would you want to put that in `application_controller.rb`? In my opinion it is only wise to put things such as methods that will handle log in detection, and finding what specific user corresponds to specific things inside it.

Comment: I.E you should keep it clean, and only keep features other `controller`'s will use.

Comment: @Muntasir Alam, about application.rb it was just as example. But what I'm talking about is, not to repeat code in every html.erb (and the only difference in this htmls will be one variable).  Or mb there is a possibility to pass variable as a parameter to html.erb?

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want a way to show  something on a page all the time? If thats the case I'll post a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that whole code into a partial? For reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Would be something like this:

```
# app/views/shared/_items.html.erb
<% items.each do |item| %>
  <!-- html stuff -->
  <!-- javascript stuff -->
  <%= # ruby stuff %>
<% end %>
```

And then you can render it like that in another view:

```
# app/views/examples/show.html.erb
<%= render 'shared/items', items: @items %>
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: That it. Break my head while trying to solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to use a **form partial**

Lets say we have a footer. We wan't to put on our website, that the website was made by us. What do we do? We create a form partial of the name

**_footer.html.erb** (`_` signifies that this is a partial, and not a whole view like `show.html.erb`)

Inside we can write

```
<div class="container">
  <footer class="footer">
    <small>
      Copyright &copy;<a href = "https://ca.linkedin.com/in/muntasir-alam-878625114">Muntasir Alam 2016</a>
    </small>
    <nav>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><%= link_to 'About', welcome_about_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Now all we have to do is `render` this view on any page we want it to appear on. Isn't that alot better than creating html on every page ;D?

**What about application_controller.rb?**

Now on to the question of `application_controller.rb`, what do we use that for?

> ApplicationController is practically the class which every other
>   controller in you application is going to inherit from (although this
>   is not mandatory in any mean).

For reference lets take a look at my own `application_controller.rb` file in one of my own apps.

Inside my class I have

```
helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def logged_in?
    current_user
  end

  def require_user
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:danger] = "You must be logged in to perform that action!"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Notice the structure. I have some code that will be used by some other controllers based on the check whether the current user is doing a specific action, or whether the user is actually logged in.

For reference see
[Partials and Layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)